# select2 'select2-selecting' events firing multiple times

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2

```
   $('#myFoodTypes').on("select2-selecting", function (e) {
                scope.chnageFoodType(e.choice.text);
            });
```

> scope.changefoodType()

method is called around 11 times,on change of myfoodTypes.

Comment: it will because of dirty checking, you need to do it with angular way or use ui-select

Comment: it is not allowing to add any ng methods on input field.

Comment: you have to make or find an angular diretive the wrap select2